# My PC (lenovo ideapad z580) is overheating while using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS

Tags: intel-graphics, ubuntu-gnome, overheating, ideapad

My PC (Lenovo Ideapad z580) is overheating while running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS.

[image: screenshot]

```
$ uname -a
Linux Mahadev 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -nnk|grep -A2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
  Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:3977]
  Kernel driver in use: i915
```

[image: top screenshot]

```
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 0:         +54.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:         +54.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

**update**

```
vivek@Mahadev:~$ stress -t 300 -c $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) && 
sensors
stress: info: [4408] dispatching hogs: 4 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
stress: info: [4408] successful run completed in 300s
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +73.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +72.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 0:         +69.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:         +72.0°C  (high = +72.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

**update**

```
    vivek@Mahadev:~$ sudo lshw -C cpu
    [sudo] password for vivek: 
  *-cpu                   
         description: CPU
        product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz
        vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       slot: CPU Socket - U3E1
       size: 1302MHz
       capacity: 2400MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 100MHz
       capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr 
pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx 
fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon 
pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni 
  pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid 
  sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx f16c lahf_lm 
  epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt 
   dtherm arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
```

**Update**
This time I edited the sensors , htop command result in image. It's getting overheated, my laptop is getting hang cause of overheating, please watch and reply. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of Very hot running with ubuntu ,,,it's not like this ques

Comment: What's your question? What are you doing on the device when it overheats? What's the output of `uname -a` and `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`?

Comment: I am just using internet or waching movie or anything it's overheating,

Comment: and command results are below as  you asked

Comment: You seem to have mistyped the second command; maybe you added a “special” space character when you held down a modifier key to enter the pipe character `|`. Could you please correct it and run it again? You can select and copy any text (e. g. in your web browser) to then paste it into any terminal emulator or text input field.

Comment: Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: On top of that, I still don't know what you're asking or what you want to achieve. Could you please [edit] your question to add an *actual* question so other readers and I know what you want?

Comment: I am getting nothing by this command.  And my problem is simple to tell you that it is over heating while using anything.If you want to know something else please tell me. thanx

Comment: Image has been added, Please check

Comment: This is still not the command the command that I asked you to run. Please run the *exact* command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA` including all spaces and punctuation. Also, what exactly is your issue with "overheating". Heat is no issue itself but it may be both the symptom and the cause of other issues.

Comment: Actually when i used window there is no heating issue but now with Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS my laptop is overheating, and it is not an issue now as you said but may be in future it will harm my laptop soon.

Comment: You're correct that heat shortens the life span of electronic components. However that only becomes a concern if the temperature approaches a component's recommended temperature threshold. If that's your only concern, could you please provide a read-out of the internal temperature sensors of your computer during a particularly hot period so we can assess its harm? See [How to use lm-sensors?](/q/53762/175814) for a very basic way to achieve that.

Comment: 54 °C is perfectly fine for most Intel CPUs *under load* and it will not feel hot through cooling components and a plastic case. The heat source almost certainly something else. To be sure it would help if you run a CPU stress test and measure the temperature again.

Comment: `stress -t 300 -c $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) && sensors` should be fine for a simple CPU stress test over 5 minutes.

Comment: It was 60 degree when I checked last time and critical was +120,so does critical temp will change all time. After some time core temprature increases, so please tell me what can I do for this.I will reply on your command soon. Thanx

Comment: I'm not clear on the thermal characteristics of your CPU.  Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C cpu` into your post This along with the other information you have posted will allow us to determine if your processor is indeed overheating.

Comment: Provided that [these match](https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-ideapad-z580/specs/) your system specs, it doesn't appear that your system is overheating. In fact the max die temp for your cpu is listed by Intel at [105 C](http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA) so in my estimation your system is running well within thermal constraints. The critical temp you are seeing isn't accurate and is as I recall adjustable.  It's for comparison purposes to the high temp. So even if the critical temp was 90 and not 105, 72 is still no concern.

Comment: Try a lightweight DE like XFCE if you think the problem is Gnome. I personally always use the lightest DE I can find even though my machine is more than capable of handling heavier DE.